# I can't run this batch script, it stops after the first command

Tags: batch-file, uninstallation

I am trying to make an uninstaller using the Batch Scripting method. I have written this program for it :

```
@echo off
set /p res = Are you sure to uninstall my summer car and all of its 
components? (NO = N, YES = Y)
if %res%==Y ( goto un )
else if %res%==y ( goto un )
else if %res%==N ( exit )
else if %res%==n ( exit )
:un
rmdir /s /q mysummercar
pause
```

But my program is not actually not working, it shows "Are you sure to uninstall my summer car and of its components (NO = N, YES = Y)", but after this message when I press Y (or y in small), the Batch file disappears. It should disappear only when N (or n in small) or other keys are pressed but it disappears while pressing Y also.
Can any body tell me the solution to run the complete Batch file, i.e., to run the "un" loop of the program??

Comment: Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `If /?`. After you've modified the code according to what you have learned, repeat the process with `Set /?`. If you wanted to make your code more robust you could replace `Set /P` with `Choice`; enter `Choice /?` to read its usage information.

Comment: @compo Would be nice if we could automatically distribute a file `else.cmd` somewhere in the users path with the content `@Echo Some !§$^&# person forgot IF syntax&Pause&Help IF&Pause`

Comment: @LotPings: This is an excellent idea! **`;)`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, but to keep focus on your current format... The main issue here is you create a variable with a space before the `=` so the variable is created as `%res %` and therefore `%res%` is not `%res %`

Additionally, we use the `if /i` switch to test case insensitive. Lastly, what will happen if a user types any other value? It will then fall through and still execute `:un` therefore just run `if /i "%res%"=="y"`

```
@echo off
set /p "res=Are you sure to uninstall my summer car and all of its components? (NO = N, YES = Y): "
if /i "%res%"=="y" rmdir /s /q mysummercar
```

A much simpler solution however would be:

```
@echo off
choice /C YN /M "Press Y to uninstall my summer car or N to Cancel"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 rmdir /s /q mysummercar
```

I strongly suggest reading up on some help files. Open `cmd.exe` and run the following:

- `choice /?`
- `set /?`
- `if /?`

Answer (score 0):

After you have learned how to use the `If`, `Set` and `Choice` commands, you may choose to reduce your code to something a little more sensible:

***Using `Set /P`***

```bat
@If Not Exist "mysummercar\" Exit /B
@Set /P "res=Uninstall my summer car and all of its components [Y,N]?"
@If /I Not "%res%"=="Y" Exit /B
@RD /S/Q "mysummercar"
```

Or slightly shorter, *(without `Not`)*:

```bat
@If Not Exist "mysummercar\" Exit /B
@Set /P "res=Uninstall my summer car and all of its components [Y,N]?"
@If /I "%res%"=="Y" RD /S/Q "mysummercar"
```

---

***Using `Choice`***

```bat
@If Not Exist "mysummercar\" Exit /B
@Choice /M "Uninstall my summer car and all of its components"
@If ErrorLevel 2 Exit /B
@RD /S/Q "mysummercar"
```

Or slightly shorter, *(with `Not`)*:

```bat
@If Not Exist "mysummercar\" Exit /B
@Choice /M "Uninstall my summer car and all of its components"
@If Not ErrorLevel 2 RD /S/Q "mysummercar"
```